# Rest Assured Patch http request returning invalid request body

Tags: java, api, rest-assured

```
RestAssured.baseURI = "https:{{baseurl}}"; 
RequestSpecification request = RestAssured.given();
      
JSONObject requestParams = new JSONObject(); 
request.header("Content-Type", "application/json"); 
request.body(requestParams.toString()); 
response = request.patch("/users/verificationcodes");
requestParams.put("codetype","registration"); 
requestParams.put("medium","email"); 
requestParams.put("address", "tahaiqq@hotmail.com");
requestParams.put("code", "123456");
```

```
{
  "address": "tahaiqq@hotmail.com",
  "code": "123456",
  "codetype": "registration",
  "medium": "email"
}
```

the request body is printing in response but instead of returning 2xx it's returning me

This response body:

```
{
  "message": "Invalid request body"
}
```

Comment: No idea what the server expects. Quick guess: with `request.body(requestParams.toString())` you set the body before you actually `put` something into the `requestParams`, and hence you send an empty body. If that's not the issue, step through the code with a debugger, consult the server documentation on what it expects, and capture the network traffic with wireshark or such. Good luck! Also see [ask].

Comment: Thanks for the help. I just solved it. Instead of sending body before I was calling the endpoint,. so it was sent as empty json. I Just removed the response = request.patch("/users/verificationcodes"); and moved down to after put request.it worked now